# Middleware execution flow

Tags: go

I cannot grasp the execution flow of this code:

```
func middlewareOne(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Executing middlewareOne")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        log.Println("Executing middlewareOne again")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        log.Println("Executing middlewareOne yupiii")
    })
}

func middlewareTwo(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Executing middlewareTwo")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        log.Println("Executing middlewareTwo again")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func final(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Executing finalHandler")
    w.Write([]byte("OK"))
}

func main() {
    finalHandler := http.HandlerFunc(final)
    http.Handle("/", middlewareOne(middlewareTwo(finalHandler)))
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Output:

```
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing middlewareOne
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing middlewareTwo
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing finalHandler
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing middlewareTwo again
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing finalHandler
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing middlewareOne again
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing middlewareTwo
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing finalHandler
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing middlewareTwo again
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing finalHandler
2019/03/25 09:16:32 Executing middlewareOne yupiii
```

Why does it print `middlewareTwo again` before `middlewareOne again`?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. But it happens because this middlewares run like it would be three nested `for` loops. Where each of them need to finnish before parent can execute again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let make the stack a tree, it's easier to understand:

```
middlewareOne()
    middlewareTwo()
        finalHandler()
            return finalHandler
        return middlewareTwo

    middlewareTwo again()
        finalHandler()
             return finalHandler()
        return middlewareTwo again

    return middleware one

middlewareOne again()
...
```

In order for `middleware one` to complete and move to `middleware one again` it needs the `middleware two` to return, as `middleware two` includes `middleware two again`, it needs to run `middleware two` again before completing.